# derivative theory problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let f be a derivable function in its domain D  and $x_0$ an interior point of D. Prove that: if $$f´(x)>g´(x) \forall x$$  and  $$f(x_0)=g(x_0) \Rightarrow f(x)>g(x) \forall x>x_0 and f(x)<g(x) \forall x<x_0$$

My attempt:

$$f´(x)-g´(x)>0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to x_0} {f(x)-f(x_0)\over x-x_0}-\lim_{x\to x_0} {g(x)-g(x_0)\over x-x_0}>0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to x_0} {f(x)-g(x)-f(x_0)+g(x_0)\over x-x_0}>0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to x_0} {f(x)-g(x)\over x-x_0}>0$$

when $$x>x_0 \Rightarrow x-x_0>0$$ hence $$\lim_{x\to x_0} {x-x_0}>0$$

so the only possibility for the quotient to be greater than $0$ is that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} {f(x)-g(x)}>0$$

hence $$f(x)-g(x)>0$$ but I don´t know if this last part is correct maybe  I can use the fact that f is derivable... I really would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The last part is not correct, because the limit-inequality needs to be true only in neighborhood of $x_0$ (i.e. locally), while you would like to $f(x) - g(x) > 0$ to hold globally. Also, there is simpler approach:

- Set $h = f-g$ so that $h' > 0$ and $h(x_0) = 0$.
- Assume that there exists $x_1$ such that $x_1 > x_0$ and $h(x_1) \leq 0$ and then use the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to infer contradiction.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$